# Take 20 random words, order them, what are the chances that the next word will become first in order?

Tags: calculus, order-statistics

I don't even know where to begin, is the language is even matter or it make no differences?

The question is as follow: Open a random English book, pick up $x$ random words. Then pick up another word. What are the chances that the last word you picked will come before the all the other words you picked in alphabetic order?

Comment: I think that you need to know the word count of the book in order to answer this.

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer can you prove that you need this info?

Comment: Maybe... there are other things that you definitely need, though. For example, what if the book has duplicate words, and you pick all of the same word?

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer I can't prove that by restricting the pickup to be all different words I will change the result. Because the same rules applies for the last word as well.

Comment: The chance of picking a word that is lexicographically before the other words depends on the book. If you (randomly) pick a book that has less than 20 unique words (maybe a children's book), what do you do? Aside from that you'd need to know the distribution of words in the book. Some words will almost always occur more frequently than other words in general. And in specific books some words will likely occur more often than they do when all of printed English is considered. Eg in novels names of the main characters will occur more frequently than they do in general. Are names even words?

Comment: @Χpẘ Names are words; What you are asking will help you answering the question: What are the chance to pick a specific word. But it's not my question. Can you prove that this information is necessary for predicting the lexicographical order of the last word?

Comment: No serious thoughts, but you may be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic. In particular, you probably should assume that the words are iid according to the distribution of the given book, which simplifies the theory.

Comment: Actually, is there any chance that the answer is just $1/21$? Some word has to be the first one, and if it's all iid from the same source... this might work but I lack confidence in probability.

Comment: @EricStucky This is my prime gues as well. But how do you prove it?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Suggest looking up the discrete Zipf distribution which was popularized by a linguist to describe distribution of words in English. The Pareto distribution is continuous analog to Zipf. The wikipedia article on Zipf says that "the" occurs 7% of the time. Since "the" is towards the end of the lexicographic order it probably won't be at the head of the list. Similarly "a" is top of order and is likely to be head of list. If "a" is third most frequently used word, Zipf says that it occurs $1/3$ as frequently as "the". As I said, tho, some words are more frequent in certain books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no words can be repeated in the list, the answer is $\frac{1}{21}$. Each of the $21$ chosen words is just as likely as any other to be the first lexicographically.

If you want to be technical, there is a very, very small chance that two of the chosen 21 words are the same word, and furthermore are (depending on how you look at it) both first. This would make the chance ever so slightly higher than $\frac{1}{21}$, by an amount dependent on the word frequencies in the source.

Comment: No, the distribution doesn't matter. It doesn't matter if some word is more prevalent than another. The key concept is that the order of choosing random words has no bearing on their lexicographical ordering.

Comment: I think that duplicates does not matter, as there can be only one alphabetically min word, even if it has duplicates in the selected set. So this problem is equal to picking 21 apples from 21 apples where one of them is green and asking what are the chances that you picked green as the last apple.